# cURL header problems when posting JSON

Tags: php, json, http, post, curl

I'm in the process of building an API, but ran into some problems when testing with cURL.

My code looks like this:

```
$people = array( array('name' => urlencode('casper'),
                       'shoesize' => urlencode(41)
                      ),
                 array('name' => urlencode('charlotte'),
                       'activated' => urlencode(1)
                      )
          );

$data = http_build_query(array('data' => json_encode($people)));
$url = '...';

$ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Connection: Keep-Alive'
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

return $result;
```

The method at the URL endpoint just returns the $_POST['data'].

This works all the way until i set my headers in cURL. Without them set, the data is passed through with no problems.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? You mention it works fine without the headers, but what goes wrong with them?

Comment: @JohnVanDeWeghe OP is using json data but not sending json data correctly . see my answer below

Comment: Problem is that i need the header types to process the request correctly. But no data get's send when setting them in cURL.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `json` header then send json data 
replace

```
$data = http_build_query(array('data' => json_encode($people)));
```

with

```
 $data = json_encode($people);
```

and fetch it in target file using `fopen('php://input','r');`

or either dont send header at all.

you can see may [**blog**](http://itsphptime.blogspot.in/2013/03/posting-json-data-with-php-curl-and.html)

Comment: I need the headers since my API should be able to handle different data formats. Thanks for the answer. I don't get why i'll have to use fopen though?

Comment: are you able to get the the desired result ? I will explain you why you need so

Comment: The request get's send when i do it that way. But i am not able to retrieve the result. Looking in the $_POST gives me an empty array. Not sure how to actually output with fopen or turn it into a PHP array. Like if i could just json_decode the data.